# Exit Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, exit

I am writing code for my exit button for my Java applet. The exit button successfully works on Eclipse. However, when I try to exit the applet from the browser, the button won't work.

I used System.exit(0)

Comment: Well, what do you expect to happen? If you want to close the applet, try googling "how to terminate java web applet" or something.

Comment: You can try to interact with JavaScript and remove your applet from the DOM. Though I don't know whether it will work...

Answer (score 0):

The code is working correctly as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea to call System.exit(0), may cause browser errors (trying to close it). Run your application in a JFrame and launch it with Web Start.

Another approach would be

```
applet.getAppletContext().showDocument(appletCloseURL);
```

and navigate to a proper URL.

Comment: So if applet name is AppletMenu and URL is applet.com, I am typing the following: AppletMenu.getAppletContext().showDocument(appletCloseapplet.com)?

Comment: For my application, I have to use JApplet, not JFrame.

Comment: Well, it's more like "real-life", and you'd need to have a web page to display there. But creating applets nowdays is not much "real-life" anyway.